# postgres procedure syntax error near »end«

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am facing an issue when I try to run my procudere. I have a table where I have all values stored in text format and try to convert to int or timestamp

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.textnummerictest(
)
LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
create or replace procedure textnummerictest()
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
 insert into sensorhistory_test(
  datetime,
  sensorid     )
 select from sensorhistory_temp (
  cast(sensorid as integer),
  datetime::timestamp       )
 end; $$
$BODY$;

ALTER PROCEDURE public.textnummerictest()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Always getting the error Syntaxerror near end.

Any help really appreciated

Comment: You have a `create or replace` inside another `create or replace`

Comment: well this is added by pgadmin for any reason. the original script is between $BODY$

Comment: Then it's a pgAdmin bug. Remove everything before the first `$BODY$` and then remove the final `$BODY$` as well.

Comment: I did so, but now end;$$ is red underlined and I get the same error

Comment: Well there is so much wrong with that statement, that it's really hard to fix. You are missing a `;` at the end of the INSERT. And your procedure doesn't have a variable or parameter named `sensorid` or `datetime`. And `select from ..` should be `select * from ...` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error....

there must be a ';' before end...